Is there a way in QGIS or GRASS to transform a polygon layer conaining paths or roads to a line layer?
What I want is to transform a layer that that contains roads or paths to a line to eventually make a network analisys.
For example from this:

Get this:


Please have a look on this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis
